# How to run a shell script before restarting a service in Monit in case of a crash

Tags: monit

I am using Monit 5.3.2 in my Linux box. I am monitoring some services using Monit.
I want to run a script before the running the restart command. 
I have used the below conditions for the same.

```
if does not exist for 2 times within 3 cycles then exec  "/bin/bash -c 'touch /tmp/somefile'" as uid someuser and gid someuser

if does not exist for 10 cycles then restart
```

Unfortunately only the restart action is getting executed.

Can anyone please help me to identify why the first rule is not executed ?
Is there are any other way to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

*This is not a definitive answer, as I am a newbie currently chasing down a similar problem.*

I currently have a suspicion that the last rule overrides all previous rules.

If so, try:

```
if does not exist for 2 times within 3 cycles 
then exec  "/bin/bash -c 'touch /tmp/somefile'" as uid someuser and gid someuser 
ELSE if does not exist for 10 cycles then restart
```